# error: unable to unlink old 'README.md' (Operation not permitted)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I did `brew update` and got a error message

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

I've searched previous posts for a workaround and I tried a host of suggested remedies but none worked.  A problem is when I fired eg. `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` I got;

> error: unable to unlink old 'README.md' (Operation not permitted)
>   fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'FETCH_HEAD'.

I used sudo chmod and chown to change a file ownership and permission but I got the same error, "Operations not permitted".

here is an output of my brew --config;

- HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
- ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
- HEAD: f550366b94ab3022d325c9f5bcad496993d80c37
- HOMEBREW_PREFIX:   /usr/local
- HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
- CPU: 8-core 64-bit
- ivybridge OS X: 10.9.3-x86_64
- Xcode: 5.1.1 CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
- Clang: 5.1 build 503 X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11 System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
- Perl: /usr/bin/perl
- Python: /usr/local/bin/python =>/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
- Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby

The brew doctor had warnings indicating my /usr/local is not writeable but I had not have any problem using brew until today.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew cleanup --force
brew update
```